# Laravel relationship with custom method

Tags: sql, laravel, ldap, relationship

Table project:

```
project_id (int)
requestor_id (uuid)
```

Table requestor:

```
requestor_id (uuid)
```

Model Project:

```
public function requestor() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Requestor', 'requestor_id', 'requestor_id');
}
```

Model Requestor has one method:

```
// this method return object users info from ldap
public function getLdapAttribute() {
    $ldapWrapper = new LdapWrapper();
    return $ldapWrapper->checkIfUuidExists($this->requestor_id, true);
}
```

Select all projects with requestor relationship:

```
$query = (new Project)->newQuery()->with(['requestor'])->get();
```

And **Question** is: 
How can I select all projects with requestor relationship and on every requestor object call method getLdapAttribute and return all as one object?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: how does any of your codes relate to sql??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the name of that "Ldap" attribute in the $appends array of the App\Requestor Class and Eloquent will automatically append a property named ldap with the value ,of the returned for the getLdapAttribute method.

[Link to the Official Laravel Documentation for this Eloquent feature !](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

As SQL query of `getLdapAttribute` method is not specified, we can fetch projects first, and then iterate over and get that attribute.

If SQL query of `getLdapAttribute` is given then we can get all the data in one query (here we get attributes after the first query of fetching projects).

```
$projects = Project::with(['requestor'])
->get()
->each(function ($project) {
    $project->requestor->getLdapAttribute();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I was using this solutions first, but Diego above suggested something better :) But thank you too.